# Play a PCM stream sampled at 16 kHz

Tags: websocket, web-audio-api, pcm

I get a input frame stream through a socket, it is a mono 32-bit IEEE floating point PCM stream sampled at 16 kHz.

I get this with the following code : [audio File sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxSqAKWrvWSHR0hIT2N1YW44U00/view)

With Audacity i can visualize this and i see a regular cuts between my audio flux:

[image: Pict of audio File]

```
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var audioBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, 256, 16000);
var BufferfloatArray;
var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 0.1;
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
source.connect(gainNode);
source.start(0);
```

---

```
socket.on('audioFrame', function(raw) {

        var context = audioCtx;

        BufferfloatArray = new Float32Array(raw);

        var src = context.createBufferSource();
        audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(BufferfloatArray);
        src.buffer = audioBuffer;
        src.connect(gainNode);
        src.start(0);

});
```

I think it is because of the sample rate of my raw buffer (16000) is different of the sample rate of my Audio context (44100), what do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a sample rate problem, because the `AudioBufferSourceNode` resamples the audio to the `AudioContext`'s rate when playing.

What you should do here, is to have a little queue of buffers you feed using the network, and then, play your buffers normally like you do, but from the buffer queue, taking extra care to schedule them (using the first parameter of the `start` method of the `AudioBufferSourceNode`) at the right time, so that the end of the previous buffer is exactly the start of the next one. You can use the `AudioBuffer.duration` parameter to achieve this (`duration` is in seconds).

Comment: I try to create a render loop for audio. Now it's better  but i still have glitch between PCM chunk. I use setInterval  and calculate delta for refreshing the buffer at the right time, but my delta isn't stable ( ~ 16, 17, 18, 19 ms) What is the best practice for that ? Is there any ring buffer in the web audio api that i can feed without the issue of swapping the buffer at the right time by myself?